# MS Access - Prevent prompt to save form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sometimes when I've made changes to the form via VBA (change in record source, control source, making controls visible or not, etc.) the user will be prompted to save the form when closing it.

Is there any way to avoid this or prevent the prompt?

Comment: `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` will disbale the warnings.

Comment: What kinds of messages does that disable? Is that a good practice or are there other ways to avoid these warnings?

Comment: Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837275.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Im posting in the answer section because I'm unable to post under comments, I'm Relatively new to this site.

Anyways, are you making the changes while other users may be using the form at the same time? That's the only thing that would make sense to me is that a user is in the form when you are making your changes which it then asks them to save the changes to the form, as it would be different from the time they first entered into the form.

Comment: Well the changes are being made by the code in the background while the user is on the form. The code is triggered by something the user does on the form.

Comment: well it seems to me if its dynamic like that. That the form would be changed for the user. and therefore, it would ask if they would want to save the form. Is there anyway you can make these changes at a time where nobody is utilizing it. and make it not dynamic. I don't see users entering information into line items cause form changes, but I also don't know your triggers you have set up. my suggestion is either do your changes at a time when nobody is utilizing the form, or if this is something that will always happen then just turn off the warning like the above mentioned.